# Replacing specific characters in python

Tags: python-2.7, replace

I have a text file with data as:

```
a   Next-hop=path
a   10.230.2.91
a   Next-hop=path
a   10.229.5.239
a   10.229.6.239
```

I want it to look like:

```
12      Next-hop=path
12      10.230.2.91
55      Next-hop=path
55      10.229.5.239
55      10.229.6.239
```

This means, each time a next-hop=path is there, the first column in text file should read data like 12,55 from another text file "numbers" which has rows like 12,55 and replace "a" in original text file. Any help to do this with python? thanks!

Comment: Please post your code so far. Also post a sample of the second input file as the description is not clear, e.g. is it a single comma separated line, or are there multiple lines in the second file?

Comment: @mhawke the second file has multiple lines, I want to pick one line from second txt file and put it in first till another "next-hop=path" is encountered.

Comment: So it's a single number per line? Post an example, and your code.

Comment: Yeah its like 12
                    15
I dont have any code for this replacement, pls guide me.

Comment: How is "12" an example of a multiline file? And _please_ update your question with a sample and code.

Answer (score 0):

You need to at first read the file

```
f = open('filename.extension')
lines = f.readlines()
```

then you can iterate through the lines and extract the `a` and `Next-hop=path`
using

```
for cur_line in lines:
    contents = cur_line.split()
```

and compare the string in the second column agains your marker. Introduce a replacment string variable and change it whenever you encounter `Next-hop=path`.
Otherwise just replace with the old value

```
if contents[1] == "Next-hop=path":
   replacementString = read_replacement_string()

contents[0] = replacementString
```

then write the new content to the file

Comment: your code looks great, but I have to read replacement string from a file, how can I use two for loops for this purpose, pls guide further. Thanks!

Comment: You can read the second file like the first one and pre-process the content to get a list of replacement strings. then you could just index the list 
`replacementStringList[rep_index]` and instead of using the code above to get a new replacement string put something like

`if contents[1] == "Next-hop=path":
     rep_index += 1 `

then replace the content like this

`contents[0] = replacementStringList[rep_index]`

Comment: @alisha Sure, that's what this site is for :) consider accepting the answer, when it actually answered the question so that it is marked answered